# Generate multiple PDF documents with loop

Tags: php, laravel, pdf-generation

Here is some code in one of my Laravel controllers to generate multiple timesheet PDF's.  It only creates 1 and Im sure its due to the return statement but how do i get it to create all PDF's?  I'm using barryvdh/laravel-dompdf.

```
public function alltimesheets(Request $request)
    {
        $weeks = Timesheet::where('week_ending', $request->week_ending)->get();
        $week_ending = Carbon::parse($request->week_ending)->format('d-m-Y');
        foreach($weeks as $hours)
        {

            $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.timesheet', compact('hours', 'week_ending'));
            $sheet = $pdf->setPaper('a4', 'landscape');
            return $sheet->download($hours->user->name.' - '.$week_ending.'.pdf');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First get all views html in one variable and then pass it to PDF.

Try the following code:

```
public function alltimesheets(Request $request)
{
    $weeks = Timesheet::where('week_ending', $request->week_ending)->get();
    $week_ending = Carbon::parse($request->week_ending)->format('d-m-Y');
    $html = '';
    foreach($weeks as $hours)
    {
        $view = view('pdf.timesheet')->with(compact('hours', 'week_ending'));
        $html .= $view->render();
    }
    $pdf = PDF::loadHTML($html);            
    $sheet = $pdf->setPaper('a4', 'landscape');
    return $sheet->download('download.pdf');  // $hours can not be accessed outside foreach. So changed the file name to `download.pdf`.
}
```

Comment: Get this error - Object of class Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF could not be converted to string

Comment: No just creates the last pdf.

Comment: @Finchy70, I have updated my code again. This time it should work. Here is the reference link of the Github package itself where the author himself has given the solution. [Click here](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/330)

Comment: Thanks.  Just had to change loadView to loadHTML and restructure my pfd.blade files.  Works great now.

Comment: your welcome. happy to help. thanks for up voting and accepting my answer.

Comment: i have tried this solution but its just concatenate the data in one pdf view,

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the answer above by [Himashu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49999146/generate-multiple-pdf-documents-with-loop/49999323#49999323). I would like to add some code which can download the multiple pdf at a specific location. This creates a separate pdf for each file.

```
$invoices = Invoices::where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->get();

    foreach($invoices as $key => $invoice)
    {
        $user_details = Users::where('id',$invoice->user_id)->first();
        $html = '';
        $view = view('pdf.invoice_compact')->with(compact('user_details','invoice'));
        $html .= $view->render();
        PDF::loadHTML($html)->save(public_path().'/bulk_invoices/'.$invoice->id.'.pdf');
    }
```