# Laravel barryvdh/laravel-dompdf multiple components of view in one pdf

Tags: laravel, dompdf

I am using barryvdh/laravel-dompdf to generate pdf.

I'm trying generate one pdf file with multiple pages from data collection the problem is that I get only first element and one page. Using foreach loop to generate pages. Also I was trying to use foreach in my blade, but then I get only the last page.

```
Controller:
public function multiplePagesPdf(Request $request)
    {
            $kuponai = Kuponas::all();
            //dd($kuponas);
            $html = '';
            foreach($kuponai as $kuponas)
            {
                $view = view('pdf.multiple')->with(compact('kuponas'));
                $html .= $view->render();
            }
            $pdf = PDF::loadHTML($html);            
            $sheet = $pdf->setPaper('a4', 'landscape');
            return $sheet->stream('sugeneruoti.pdf');             

    }
```

Maybe problem in my blade file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Dovanų kuponas</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="coupon">
    <div class="page">
      <div class="subpage">
        <div class="container" style="
              width: 21cm;
              height: 16cm;
              position: absolute;
              top: 6.8cm;
              font-family: DejaVu Sans;
              background: white;
            ">
         <h2>{{!! $kuponas->kupono_nr !!}}</h2>
          <h3 style="margin-left: 3.2cm">
            Dovanų kupono numeris:
            <span style="color: black"></span>
          </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
<style>
  @page {
    size: A4;
    margin: 0;
  }

  @media print {
    .page {
      margin: 0;
      border: initial;
      border-radius: initial;
      width: initial;
      min-height: initial;
      box-shadow: initial;
      background: initial;
      page-break-after: always;
    }
  }
</style>
```

Comment: this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49999146/generate-multiple-pdf-documents-with-loop

Comment: i tried exactly the same question to use maybe problem in my blade

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are certain things that are wrong in the code snippet you have provided, I will explain those first then provide correct way of doing it(for which I get results).

- Firstly

you have used with & compact together, I don't know if it gets correct results but you should use any one of them or use array syntax of view method.

- Secondly

what you are doing it you are rendering the view to html & then concating it, so , your html would look like,

```
<html>
.... content
</html>
<html>
.... content
</html>
& so on.
```

- Thirdly

You css is messed up & not working as you want because of inline css you have added.

### Solution

I would have used [View Components](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade#components-and-slots) to create similar views with different data.
So we would create a component in resources/views/components/single.blade.php (here I have named it single).
I have added your repeative code in the component single from your view. Now your coupon div class is in the component single.

```
<div class="coupon">
    <div class="page">
      <div class="subpage">
        <div>
         <h2>{{ $kuponas->kupono_nr }}</h2>
          <h3>
            Dovanų kupono numeris:
            <span></span>
          </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Then in your view,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<head>
  <title>Dovanų kuponas</title>
  <style>
    .page-break {
    page-break-after: always;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  @php $count = 0;@endphp
  @foreach ($kuponai as $kuponas)
  @php $count++ @endphp
    <div class="container {{ (count($kuponai)-1 >= $count) ? 'page-break' : '' }}">
        @component('pdf.components.single', ['kuponas' => $kuponas])
        @endcomponent
    </div>    
  @endforeach
</body>

</html>
```

use page-break class to create breaks, I have used count condition to remove one extra page break. I am passing the data of kuponas to the component.

Finally change your controller,

```
public function multiplePagesPdf(Request $request)
    {
        $kuponai = Kuponas::all();
        //dd($kuponas);
        
        $view = view('pdf.multiple', ['kuponai' => $kuponai]);
        $html = $view->render();
        $pdf = PDF::loadHTML($html)->setPaper('a4', 'landscape');            
        return $pdf->stream('sugeneruoti.pdf');
    }
```